# Reverse Move-To-Front transform

Tags: algorithm

given: A-> L-> G-> O-> R-> I-> T-> H-> M-> U-> S

Now I have to give the shortest sequence which, using Move-To-Fron, gives me:

G-> L-> A-> M-> O-> R-> H-> I-> T-> U-> S

The result is: H,R,O,M,A,L,G

I might can guess it but I just lack a systematical way to solve this. Would be nice if someone can show me the proper though process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is only moved to front. That means `G` must be moved last. Push `G` to the stack, and forget it.

The resulting strings are `ALORITHMUS` and `LAMORHITUS`.

For them, `L` must be moved last. Push it to the stack, and forget it. Now you have `AORITHMUS` and `AMORHITUS`.

Rinse and repeat, until the remaining strings compare equal (no more moves required). The final stack contains the result, in the correct order.

Be careful with comparison. A naive implementation results in a quadratic time complexity. There is a way to avoid it.